# Why does my Swift code try and call the wrong init method?

Tags: swift

I have the following Swift class:

```
public class Tree {

  var obj_ : OpaquePointer

  public init(fromCPtr obj:OpaquePointer) {
    obj_ = obj
  }

  convenience init(_ levels:Int32) {
    var rv : OpaquePointer?
    Tree_Tree_create(levels, &rv)
    self.init(fromCPtr:rv!)
  }

  deinit
  {
    Tree_Tree_dispose(obj_)
  }
}
```

And the following test code:

```
import Foundation                                                                                                                                                                
import Tree

let t = Tree(4)
print(t.data())
```

I compile the Tree module with:

```
swiftc Tree.swift -import-objc-header Tree-Bridging-Header.h -L. -lTree_c -emit-module -emit-module-path build/Tree.swiftmodule -emit-library -module-name Tree -o build/Tree
```

This works without errors or warnings.

I compile my test code with:

```
swiftc TestTree.swift -Ibuild/
```

and get the following error:

```
TestTree.swift:4:14: error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'OpaquePointer'
let t = Tree(4)
```

Why is Swift selecting the pointer overload? As I understand things, Swift should not select the pointer init method unless I call `init(fromCPtr some_pointer)`.
Using `Tree(Int32(4))` in the test makes no difference.

How can I get Swift to select the correct init method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
convenience init(_ levels:Int32) {
```

This is not a `public` initializer. Add `public` to make it visible outside the module. The default access level is `internal`, which is only visible inside the module.